# matching tables under specific order

Tags: mysql

I have two tables

```
             Table A    
username    startcity   finalcity
   p            A          B
   t            C          D
   u            E          C


             Table B    
username    startcity1  finalcity1
   e           A           F 
   e           B           K
   f           C           D
   g           A           C
```

and i want to match the tables under the criteria (A.startcity =B.startcity1   OR A.finalcity=B.finalcity1). The point i can't deal with that is that i want to start with first row of table A and **complete the check with all rows of table B before start matching the second row of table A with table B**. As a result, i expect table C

```
            Table C 
username    startcity   finalcity
   p            A           B
   e            A           F 
   g            A           C
   p            C           D
   f            C           D
   p            E           C
   g            A           C
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe an ORDER BY A.startcity could give you the desired results?

Comment: Define 'first row'. Why is it 'first'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following query:-

```
SELECT A.username, A.startcity, A.finalcity
FROM A INNER JOIN B
WHERE A.A.startcity =B.startcity1 3
OR A.finalcity=B.finalcity1
ORDER BY A.startcity;
```

This might be helpful to you.